# Changing site while asking should change text in caption

Tags: bug, ios-app, site-name

In the iOS-app it's possible to change site where you want to ask question. But in this case caption text should reflect actual site's name instead of where you opened asking page. E.g. I have been started on MSE, but have changed it to SO as actual site:

> [image: change site caption]

- App Version: 1.7.0
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)